# Rails i18n not finding my custom error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

What's wrong with my locale:

I'm getting:

```
Hotel translation missing: pt-BR.activemodel.errors.models.hotel_selector.attributes.id.must_be_filled
```

And my yml is like this:

```
pt-BR:
  activemodel:
    attributes:
      csv_invite:
        file_path: Arquivo
        group_id: Grupo
      hotel_selector:
        id: Hotel
    errors:
      models:
        hotel_selector:
          id:
            must_be_filled: deve ser preenchido
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot the `attributes` key.
Silly me.

Comment: :-)  A cup of tea may help find a solution.

Comment: uma bem gelada ajuda mais ainda.. hehehehe